# How can GDAX pay no fees while transfering Bitcoin between wallets?

Tags: network, transit-fees

How is that possible that using GDAX you don't pay network fees (than can go up to 30 USD) to move bitcoins between wallets?

How can GDAX pay all these transactions fee for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDAX is a centralized exchange, they don't actually transfer the Bitcoins between wallets. They have a database that associates every account with how much Bitcoin they are worth.This is why transferring from Coinbase to GDAX is free, because it is the same company running both platforms.

Comment: GDAX also covers the transaction fee for withdraws to arbitrary wallets which are not sitting on the GDAX backend. It seems that this fee was the one the OP was asking about which would mean the question hasn't been answered.

Comment: I was not asking between gdax and coinbase, but between gdax and other wallets

Comment: But the answer stays the same, GDAX to Coinbase or GDAX to any other GDAX owned wallet.

Comment: binance wallet are not owned by gdax